# Calculating representative sample of pareto distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, pareto-distribution

I have a Pareto-distributed population of size N.
If I wish to be 99% confident, with 0.75% margin of error, and empirically 35% made a good sample  - what will be the formula to derive the sufficient sample of N to be representative? Does it even matter that my population is Pareto distributed?

For a long time I was certain I have a 1-sided normally distributed population, and recently I realized it's not the case. I used to calculate the sample needed in the following way (code from a script of mine):

```
error_margin = 0.0075
confidence = 0.99
expected_sample = 0.35
alpha = 1-confidence
n_sided = 1 # 1 or 2-sided test
z_crit = stats.norm.ppf(1-alpha/n_sided)
---
ideal_coverage = (((pow(z_crit, 2)*(expected_sample*(1-expected_sample)))/pow(error_margin, 2))/
                                      (1+((pow(z_crit, 2)*(expected_sample*(1-expected_sample)))/(pow(error_margin, 2)*u_values))))/u_values
```

How do I calculate z score for Pareto anyways?

Thanks,
Self-taught

Comment: What do you mean by "representative"?

Comment: A subset of a population that seeks to accurately reflect the characteristics of the larger group